# SliderAccess is displaying in wrong way in JQuery DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django-templates, datetimepicker

I have a problem with proper displaying sliderAccess in TimePicker.

First problem is that buttons aren't displaying in line with slider (like in [examples](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/jQuery-SliderAccess/)), but below slider.

Second thing is that buttons are displaying only for the first slider (hours), but i need it also for second slider (minutes).

[image]

**select_datetime.html**:

```
<input class="datepicker form-control hasDatepicker" id="id_date" name="date" placeholder="Date" readonly="readonly" required="" type="text">
```

**base.html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datetimepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    hour: 8,
    minute: 0,
    stepMinute: 5,
    addSliderAccess: true,
    sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false, },
  });
});

/* SliderAccess */
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
    sliderAccess: function(options){
        options = options || {};
        options.touchonly = options.touchonly !== undefined? options.touchonly : true; // by default only show it if touch device

        if(options.touchonly === true && !("ontouchend" in document)){
          return $(this);
        }

        return $(this).each(function(i,obj){
          var $t = $(this),
            o = $.extend({},{
                    where: 'after',
                    step: $t.slider('option','step'),
                    upIcon: 'ui-icon-plus',
                    downIcon: 'ui-icon-minus',
                    text: false,
                    upText: '+',
                    downText: '-',
                    buttonset: true,
                    buttonsetTag: 'span',
                    isRTL: false
                  }, options),
            $buttons = $('<'+ o.buttonsetTag +' class="ui-slider-access">'+
                    '<button data-icon="'+ o.downIcon +'" data-step="'+ (o.isRTL? o.step : o.step*-1) +'">'+ o.downText +'</button>'+
                    '<button data-icon="'+ o.upIcon +'" data-step="'+ (o.isRTL? o.step*-1 : o.step) +'">'+ o.upText +'</button>'+
                  '</'+ o.buttonsetTag +'>');

          $buttons.children('button').each(function(j, jobj){
            var $jt = $(this);
            $jt.button({
                    text: o.text,
                    icons: { primary: $jt.data('icon') }
                  })
              .click(function(e){
                    var step = $jt.data('step'),
                      curr = $t.slider('value'),
                      newval = curr += step*1,
                      minval = $t.slider('option','min'),
                      maxval = $t.slider('option','max'),
                      slidee = $t.slider("option", "slide") || function(){},
                      stope = $t.slider("option", "stop") || function(){};

                    e.preventDefault();

                    if(newval < minval || newval > maxval){
                      return;
                    }

                    $t.slider('value', newval);

                    slidee.call($t, null, { value: newval });
                    stope.call($t, null, { value: newval });
                  });
          });

          // before or after
          $t[o.where]($buttons);

          if(o.buttonset){
            $buttons.removeClass('ui-corner-right').removeClass('ui-corner-left').buttonset();
            $buttons.eq(0).addClass('ui-corner-left');
            $buttons.eq(1).addClass('ui-corner-right');
          }

          // adjust the width so we don't break the original layout
          var bOuterWidth = $buttons.css({
                marginLeft: ((o.where === 'after' && !o.isRTL) || (o.where === 'before' && o.isRTL)? 10:0),
                marginRight: ((o.where === 'before' && !o.isRTL) || (o.where === 'after' && o.isRTL)? 10:0)
              }).outerWidth(true) + 5;
          var tOuterWidth = $t.outerWidth(true);
          $t.css('display','inline-block').width(tOuterWidth-bOuterWidth);
        });
  }
});

})(jQuery);
/* SliderAccess end */
</script>
```

Comment: H have run your code on an online javascript editor and everything seem to work fine. See link below:
http://js.do/code/testdtpicker

Comment: Only thing that i have modified is the class of the datepicker
From: class="datepicker form-control hasDatepicker"
TO: class="datepicker"
Can you check that?

Comment: Yes, probably it's a solution but unfortunately I can't change <input> class due to requirements of my framework. Anyways, thanks for help!